# cannot create accurev workspace after removing and changing one of the same name

Tags: accurev

I am aware that [removing a workspace does not make its name available again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3295951/remove-a-workspace-in-accurev).

I had a workspace called `MyWSpace`.  I removed that workspace using `accurev rmws MyWSpace` and it said it was remove successfully.  I then tried to rename it using `accurev chws -w MyWSpace _MyWSpace`, which it also said was successful.

However, now I have problems.  I made a new workspace using `accurev mkws -b MyStream -w MyWSpace2 -l /home/user/MyWSpace`.  I now want to rename it using `accurev chws -w MyWSpace2 MyWSpace` and I get `There is already a stream named`.  So I executed `accurev remove stream MyWSpace_username`, which it said was successful, but when I try to rename my new workspace again, I get the same error.

I'm at a loss for how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you create a workspace/stream, that name is taken forever, even if you rename/delete the workspace/stream.

So at some point in time, the name MyWSpace was used.